# Confused in rdbuf()

Tags: c++

#### **Here is my simple code:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int foo;
    std::cin.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
    std::cin>>foo; // what'll happen at this line? whatever I'll input will go to cout's buffer then to foo , right?
}
```

What I was thinking that above code will set `cin`'s buffer to `cout`'s buffer so when I will input some number it'll will be outputted also. I guess I'm confused with my own program. Can anyone tell me what's going on in the program?

Also, if I add one more line at end : `std::cout<<foo;` , then it prints random number which means foo never gets input. So what's happening overall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stream is responsible for the formatting and delegates the IO to the streambuf (which thus do more than buffering, it executes the IO as well).

So with `std::cin.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf())` you are asking to cin to do its input using the streambuf of cout, which probably is not ready for doing input. So `std::cin>>foo` will fail.

Comment: Perfect explanation, Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking, but am not sure, that the reason that foo is not being inputted is because after you set cin's buffer to cout, the line

```
std::cin >> foo;
```

will actually become

```
std::cout >> foo;
```

in which the use of the >> operator is incorrect, so nothing happens to foo.

Then, when you use

```
std::cout << foo;
```

it will output foo, which will be non-initialized, therefore a random number.